# how to add Pyinstaller to path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

how can I add Pyinstaller to the path (on macOS)

because when I use the Pyinstaller command it says;

```
  zsh: zsh: command not found: pyinstaller
```

and I think the error occurs because Pyinstaller its not in the path; I already installed Pip3 install Pyinstaller.

```
  # after installing Pyinstaller:
 Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I couldn't find a way to add it to the path on Mac although I found an answer to how to do in on windows,

Comment: In your `.zshrc` add `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/pyinstaller`.

Comment: The correct path should be somewhere in the `pip install` output

Comment: @dibery i created a .zshrc file using ''touch ~/.zshrc'' and opened it and added ** 'export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-package.'**    but still the result is same